# c++ how to obtain the type of the object?

Tags: c++

how can i obtain the `typeid` of the following: `T& object`; where `T` is: `template<class T>`. I am working in c++ code. I did test:

```
const std::type_info& ObjT= typeid(object);
std::cout<<"******the objT is: "<<&ObjT<<std::endl;
```

But it crashes. Why?

Comment: Did it crash at runtime, or fail to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you include:

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

and perhaps you should send

```
std::cout << typeid(object).name() << std::endl;
```

And perhaps there is a problem in the fact that you are doing && on the object.

look at the example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)

Comment: and how to save the type in ObjT? Yes I did include the library typeinfo

Comment: I did check but it still doesn't print the typeid:(. WHY?

Comment: @JustMe: you are not really saving the typeinfo, you are saving a reference to it. if you wanna save it you should delete the &'s.

Comment: have errror: conversion from const char* to non-scalar type const std::typeinfo request.:( why? how to clear this up?

Comment: it prints the name including some new characters.why? got any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a human-readable name, use the `name()` method:

```
std::cout<<"******the objT is: "<<ObjT.name()<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are doing?

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> 
struct S {
};

int main() {
    S <int> a;
    S <int> & object = a;
    const std::type_info & ObjT = typeid( object );
    std::cout << "******the objT is: "<< ObjT.name() <<  std::endl;
}
```

This works for me with GCC 4.5.1.

Comment: That will certainly compile, but I really doubt it does what the OP wants - you're printing the address of the `type_info` object.

Comment: I think the main thing that we can infer from the OP's code is that they don't know how to code what they actually want.

Comment: it's the address. how to print the name?

Comment: I'm with Jefromi on that one ;-)